# Something changing how many keys are read in Jedit

Tags: jedit

Occasionally something will happen in Jedit (I guess I am pressing some key sequence that is putting me into some other mode), and the keys I press show up as all sort of strange symbols. I don't know how to fix the behavior; closing and re-opening Jedit doesn't help. The only thing that works is restarting my computer.

I also notice that sometimes there is a difference between right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and left <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. For example, right now  <kbd>left ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> will save my file, but <kbd>right ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> inserts the symbol ß into the buffer.

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is probably more a OS thing than a jEdit (not Jedit) thing.
You can see the key events that are sent to jEdit with the help of `Utilities -> Troubleshooting -> Keyboard Tester...` and you will probably see the your OS is sending wrong things to jEdit. Maybe you are using Windows and pressed the default `Alt+TAB` shortcut to change the keyboard layout. You can also show the language bar in your Taskbar to always see which keyboard layout is selected currently.
Oh, btw. if you close jEdit with the red cross in the upper right, you are probably only closing the View, not quitting jEdit. If you press `Ctrl+Q` or select `File -> Exit`, then jEdit is really closed and can be restarted. If you still think this is a jEdit rather than an OS problem, you might consider opening a bug ticket for jEdit.

Comment: I had to wait for the problem to return, but it finally has. Right now when I type the "/" key, I'm getting an "e" with an accent. This is currently only happening in JEdit, not in any of the other programs I'm running. Inputting the "/" key into the key troubleshooter, JEdit shows: "Event KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=0x0,keyChar=0xe9,modifiers=0x0,consumed=0 filtered
Event KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0x0,keyChar=0xe9,modifiers=0x0,consumed=0 passed
==> Translated to <0,e9>
Event KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=0x0,keyChar=0xe9,modifiers=0x0,consumed=0 passed". But I have no idea what I'm looking at...

Comment: What you are looking at is that jEdit does not translate your key presses, but directly gets the key for e with accent. It still looks to me like you having a different keyboard layout selected. Did you check in the language toolbar or how it is called in english. That it is only happening in jEdit (not JEdit) does not mean much, as Windoze partly remembers per Application which keyboard layout you switched to. You have to look at the language toolbar while jEdit is the active window like I said. :-)

Comment: OK. I will wait for the behavior to occur again and check language settings. I don't see the language bar in my task bar though. Is it equivalent to go to _Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Change keyboards or other input methods_?

Comment: Almost I think. I have german Windoze here, but I think I know in which dialog you are. There should be three tabs in this dialog if I see the same dialog than you. There on the second tab you can control where to show the language bar, either in the task bar, floating or not shown at all.